# npm i conflict issue after update my nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-sass

I upgraded my node from 14 to 16; and faced this problem while doing `npm i`, see screenshot to see the problem:

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti8EI.png)

I have tried to remove node modules, clearing cache, doing `npm i` again; didn't help.

Also tried doing `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

How can I resolve such dependency conflicts?

Comment: don't put links to screenshots, put the actual error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message itself tells you what the problem is and how you might be able to solve it.

You have `sass-loader@8.0.2` installed which has `node-sass@^4.0.0` as a peer dependency. But in your root project you have `node-sass@^7.0.1` installed.

If you look at the [`sass-loader` changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1240-2021-12-07), you can see that they added support for `node-sass` v7 in v12.4.0.

So, your solution seems to be either upgrade `sass-loader` to v12.4.0 or later (v13.0.2 is the latest), or downgrade `node-sass` to v4.x.x.

If you run into other problems, the `node-sass` GitHub page has a troubleshooting guide at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md.

Node v16 comes bundled with a newer version of npm, so your problem most likely stems not from the node version upgrade per se, but from an npm upgrade. From https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies (emphasis mine):

> Automatically installing peer dependencies is an exciting new feature introduced in npm 7. In previous versions of npm (4-6), peer dependencies conflicts presented a warning that versions were not compatible, but would still install dependencies without an error. **npm 7 will block installations if an upstream dependency conflict is present that cannot be automatically resolved.**

To help further troubleshoot this, it would be helpful to know the exact version of node (`node --version`) and npm (`npm --version`) you are running, as well as the contents of your `package.json` and your lockfile (`package-lock.json`). Although the above info should be enough for you to know why this error occurred (npm v7 breaking change) and what you can do to solve it (upgrade `sass-loader`).